# Split string into array with many char pro items

Tags: python, string, function, split

I have a string and I want an array of str for example:

```
"hello world"
["hel", "lo ", "wor", "ld"]
```

or

```
["hell", "o wo", "rld"]
```

I see that `list(message)` would be ok but just for

```
["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d", ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your criteria for splitting the string? i.e. into a certain number of parts, into parts of a certain length, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)) if not i % 3]
['hel', 'lo ', 'wor', 'ld']
```

For a more general solution (i.e. custom-defined splits), try this function:

```
def split_on_parts(s, *parts):
    total = 0
    buildstr = []
    for p in parts:
        buildstr.append(s[total:total+p])
        total += p
    return buildstr

s = 'hello world'
print split_on_parts(s, 3, 3, 3, 3)
print split_on_parts(s, 4, 3, 4)
```

Which produces the output:

```
['hel', 'lo ', 'wor', 'ld']
['hell', 'o w', 'orld']
```

*OR* if you're really in the mood for a one-liner:

```
def split_on_parts(s, *parts):
    return [s[sum(parts[:p]):sum(parts[:p+1])] for p in range(len(parts))]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> def split_length(s, l):
...     return [s[i:i+l] for i in range(0, len(s), l)]
... 
>>> split_length("hello world", 3)
['hel', 'lo ', 'wor', 'ld']
>>> split_length("hello world", 4)
['hell', 'o wo', 'rld']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst = ['he', 'llo', ' wo', 'rld']
>>> ''.join(lst)
'hello world'
>>> s = 'hello world'
>>> list(s)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Those are the basics; if you have any specific requirements, comment on this post and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
`list` is a python key word. You can use list and indexing power of list to manipulate your result.

In [5]: s = 'hello world'

In [6]: s.split()
Out[6]: ['hello', 'world']

In [7]: list(s)
Out[7]: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s
'hello world'
>>> filter(lambda n: n != ' ', re.split("(o|wo)", s))
['hell', 'o', 'wo', 'rld']
>>> filter(lambda n: n != ' ', re.split("(lo|wor)", s))
['hel', 'lo', 'wor', 'ld']
```

Not sure how (by what criteria) exactly it was meant to be split though.